# Time and date in JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating simple web app that shows you what date and time is it now. It works good but i want to make it to be more dynamic so you can see time counting. What is best way to do this?

```
var hdate = document.getElementById('time');
var body = document.querySelector('body');
var bgM = document.getElementsByClassName('bgMorning')

var today = new Date();
var date = today.getFullYear()+'-'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+today.getDate();
var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
var dateTime = date+' '+time;

hdate.textContent = dateTime;
```

Comment: Update your HTML every X seconds....

Comment: check this out: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_countdown.asp

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Timeouts_and_intervals

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if your code is the best, but you can just wrap it in a setInterval.

```js
setInterval(function(){
    var hdate = document.getElementById('time');
    var body = document.querySelector('body');
    var bgM = document.getElementsByClassName('bgMorning')

    var today = new Date();
    var date = today.getFullYear()+'-'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+today.getDate();
    var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + 
    today.getSeconds();
    var dateTime = date+' '+time;

    console.log(dateTime)
}, 1000)
```

The second argument in the setIterval function is the interval that the code runs in miliseconds. So this will print to the console every second (1000ms -> 1s)

Answer (score 0):

you could write your code inside an interval like this to update it every second.

```
setInterval(function(){ 
      //write you code here to be executed every second
    }, 1000);
```

you'll need to re-render your display element too. Use something like this

```
<html>
  <p id="displayElement"></p>

  <script>
    //use this code inside your setInterval function so it re-renders every second
    document.getElementById("displayElement").innerHTML = `<p>${time}</p>`;
  </script>
</html>
```

let me know how that works!

Answer (score 0):

- You just need to call `setInterval(func, interval_milliseconds)`.
- Also try using template literals (e.g. `${hours}:${minutes}`) to construct your strings in a more readable style.
- Use `let` as opposed to `var` unless you need to support old versions of I.E.

```js
let timeEl = document.getElementById('time');

let updateTimeEl = () => {
  let today = new Date();
  let date = `${today.getFullYear()}-${today.getMonth() + 1}-${today.getDate()}`;
  let time = `${today.getHours()}:${today.getMinutes()}:${today.getSeconds()}`;
  timeEl.textContent = `${date} ${time}`;
};

setInterval(updateTimeEl, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="time"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
 function startTime() {
      var today = new Date();
      var h = today.getHours();
      var m = today.getMinutes();
      var s = today.getSeconds();
      // add a zero in front of numbers<10
      m = checkTime(m);
      s = checkTime(s);
      hdate.textContent = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
      //    document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
      t = setTimeout(function() {
        startTime()
      }, 500);
    }
    startTime(); //it starts the timer

function checkTime(i) {
    if (i < 10) {
        i = "0" + i;
    }
    return i;
}
```